# c programming put a hexa into char

Tags: c, hex, arp

I have

```
    unsigned char src_mac[6];
```

that holds values with the %02x format.For example to find the value in src_mac[0] i do:

```
    printf("%02x\n",src_mac[0]);
```

I want to know how to put values in src_mac(I need to put a mac adress saved as a string into src_mac and then put the mac adress into a ether_arp structure.

Comment: `scanf` is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't read the mac from the keyboard

Comment: ok, `sscanf` if it's a string and not from stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing my answer... i misread it

Anyway, try this `sscanf` with `hhx` as parameters... it means it will read an hex value and will store it as a char (unlikely the default that store the value as int)

```
sscanf(string_mac, "%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx:%hhx", &src_mac[5], &src_mac[4], &src_mac[3], 
                                                    &src_mac[2], &src_mac[1], &src_mac[0]);
```

Comment: hi.I know how to memcpy,I just don't know how to fill the unsigned char array used for memcpy(src_mac)

Comment: I get the  warning format '%x' expects argument of type int but the argument is of type 'unsigned char *'

Comment: @Emil is damn right... i updated the answer to make scanf read an hex and put it into a uint8_t